# Reference JOINed MySQL data like JSON table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

The title may be weird, as I'm not sure how to word what I'm doing.

I am building a roster system that will be sorted by designations (think Division, Company, Platoon, etc.). I want this display to be completely dynamic, and I am trying to be as slick as possible in doing it.

In the same database I have 2 tables that are not equal, though they share a couple column names where sometimes the data values are equal, sometimes they aren't. The table `tali_personnel_designations_weights` stores the categories of designation (Division, Company, etc.) while table `tali_personnel_designations` stores the actual designations (3rd Infantry Division, Kilo Company, etc.). There are a bunch of things going on, but the answer to 1 will get me back on the road. Both tables have a column named 'name' which contains, well, the name of that entry, such as Division for the _weights and 3rd Infantry Division for the designation. In my SQL I want to be able to select both names, but as it is below the only return is from tali_personnel_designations_weights, as if the first table was re-written in the result.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tali_personnel_designations JOIN tali_personnel_designations_weights ON tali_personnel_designations.designation_weight_id=tali_personnel_designations_weights.designation_weight_id ORDER BY tali_personnel_designations_weights.weight DESC, tali_personnel_designations.weight DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $SQL);

while ($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name = $db_field['name'];
    echo $name; //output is value for 'name' in tali_personnel_designations_weights
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

What I'm trying to do, if you can visualize it:

```
$designation_name = $db_field['tali_personnel_designations.name']; //output 3rd Infantry Division
$designationweight_name = $db_field['tali_personnel_designations_weights.name']; //output Division
```

I understand the easy fix for this is renaming the columns so that 'name' does not conflict, but I'm trying to learn something new here!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No need to change columns you can do this via sql: select tablename.fieldname as newFieldname

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still need all of the columns, so want to use the `*` wildcard. The below did not work. Syntax issue?   `$SQL = "SELECT tali_personnel_designations.name AS designation_name, tali_personnel_designations_weights.name AS designation_weight_name, * FROM tali_personnel_designations JOIN tali_personnel_designations_weights ON tali_personnel_designations.designation_weight_id=tali_personnel_designations_weights.designation_weight_id ORDER BY tali_personnel_designations_weights.weight DESC, tali_personnel_designations.weight DESC";`

Comment: Use Tablename.* instead to select all columns of one table

Comment: What do you set Tablename.* AS?

Comment: Referencing with `'tali_personnel_designations.name'` using the below, I'm told that value is not defined. `$SQL = "SELECT tali_personnel_designations.*, tali_personnel_designations_weights.* FROM tali_personnel_designations JOIN tali_personnel_designations_weights ON tali_personnel_designations.designation_weight_id=tali_personnel_designations_weights.designation_weight_id ORDER BY tali_personnel_designations_weights.weight DESC, tali_personnel_designations.weight DESC";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT
    T.*, 
    T.name AS designation_name,
    TW.name AS designation_weight_name
FROM tali_personnel_designations T
JOIN tali_personnel_designations_weights TW
    ON T.designation_weight_id=TW.designation_weight_id
ORDER BY TW.weight DESC, T.weight DESC
```

Then when using the result you can get the `$db_field['designation_name']` and `$db_field['designation_weight_name']`, and don't mind of the (also present) `$db_field['name']`.

Note that using alias for the table names makes it much more readable.

Comment: Referencing `$db_field['designation_weight_name']` works, but the rest doesn't. `$db_field['tali_personnel_designations.weight']` is one that should be represented by the wildcard, but an error states it is undefined.

Comment: You shoudn't write `$db_field['tali_personnel_designations.weight']` but `$db_field['weight']`. Now, form that I realize you don't have _only_ `name` as a shared column identifier. So for `weight` (and maybe other ones?) you must do the same as for `name`, i.e. explicitly use a column alias like `T.weight AS desination_name_weight`. Note that you have to give alias only to the columns you want to use from the result in PHP; in the SQL part, don't mind.

Comment: And I need all the columns from the 2nd table as well. Would adding the `TW.*` be alright to do?

Comment: For the `TW.*``, yes.

Comment: It's not what I was hoping, but it is better than what my alternative was. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks to have accepted my answer. But _how_ is it not what you're hoping? Feel free to explain it more precisely.